# Is there an elegant way to update model relations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am using Ruby on Rails, however am interested in a general solution as well. Lets say I have a model users, a model cuisines, and a relational table connecting the two allowing a user to have a list of 'favorite cuisines'. The user is presented with a list of all the cuisines and can check or uncheck them individually. For example lets say Alice starts off liking American, Indian, and Chinese food. She then unchecks Chinese and adds in Thai and hits save. Whats the best way to go about updating the relational table?

I have three solutions, but since this operation seems so common I was hoping for a more elegant solution. If there isn't, what is the standard way to do this?

- keep a set of added and a set of removed, and make sure they have no overlap
- drop all of the users favorite foods and insert the selected ones
- make ajax calls to update each individual add and remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `association_ids` approach.  Instead of looking for a list cuisines and then assigning them to the user, just get a list of their ids and assign it to `user.cuisine_ids`.  Saving the record will generate the association records for you.  Since you're using checkboxes, be wary of the scenario where a user unchecks everything and then saves.  What usually happens is no change is saved keeping the old selected cuisines selected.  This can be easily fixed by adding a `nil` hidden value with the same name as the checkboxes.